# User permission issues in OS X

Tags: osx

[OS X 10.9.4] Three questions, but they're really all part of the same thing.

Machine has one administrative user and one limited user (in addition to built-in root and a guest user). I'm really the only user, but, for security reasons, I prefer to use a login with limited privileges. This raises several problems when I try to work under the hood.

1. If I `sudo Administrator` from the limited user's login, a pw is requested. But the Admin's pw is rejected. I can't figure out why or what to do about that.
2. When I log in as administrator and try to update an app (from Terminal) that was installed from the admin login to usr/local/bin/..., the operation is denied because I (Administrator) don't have write permissions to the necessary directories. But they're usr/local/ directories, and I've already installed there, so how could I not have sufficient privileges?
3. I don't want to put the limited user on the sudoers list, because that would compromise the security framework, but I would like to do some admin things from the limited user's login. In Windows, UAC allows that; and in KDE/Fedora, I can do that (very similarly to Windows). I can't find anything comparable in OS X. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1

I assume you're doing something like `sudo -u admin_user some_command...` (run `some_command` as `admin_user`). You mentioned that you have not put the limited user on the sudoers list; therefore the limited user will not be able to invoke `sudo` *at all*. Asking for the password is just a formality, and it will reject the attempt no matter what you enter. I don't know why it was designed that way, but that's how it works. You have to add a `sudoers` entry allowing the limited user to invoke `sudo` as the administrative user. Or just use `su`, which should not require any such configuration.

Here's a `/etc/sudoers` line you might use:

```
# From left to right: allow limited_user, from any host, to
# sudo as admin_user and run any command.
limited_user ALL=(admin_user) ALL
```

Note, however, that `sudo` will ask you for `limited_user`'s password, *not* `admin_user`'s. On the other hand, `su` will ask you for `admin_user`'s password.

See `man 5 sudoers` for more information on `/etc/sudoers`. Be warned: the syntax descriptions are very complicated.

### Part 2

As far as the Unix/BSD part of OS X is concerned, administrators are no different from any other user. If `/usr/local/bin` is root-owned and has the usual rwxr-xr-x permissions, then you have to be root (i.e. become root via `sudo`) to write to it, no matter what privileges System Preferences says you have. You haven't said what it was you installed or how you installed it, but if it asked for a password, then `sudo` was probably used.

### Part 3

The usual Unix way to allow non-root users limited access to certain parts of the filesystem is to use groups. I'm not sure what UAC-like system you're referring to in Fedora/KDE, but if it's not SELinux or ACLs, then it's user and group management. I can't speak to how Windows access control works.

For example, if you want to grant both `admin_user` and `limited_user` write access to `/usr/local/bin`, you might create an `installation` group in System Preferences (Users & Accounts), add `admin_user` and `limited_user` to it, and then `chown root:installation /usr/local/bin; chmod ug+rwx /usr/local/bin`. `/usr/local/bin` will then have rwxrwxr-x permissions (owner read/write/list, group read/write/list, others read/list only).

There might be a more Mac-specific way to do what I just described. My experience is limited to more traditional *nix systems.

Comment: You answered about two or three tiers of questions that would have come up. Thanks for a thoughtful and helpful response.